# How to get Jquery response in 2 variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the next code in javascript:

```
      $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "get_link.php",
        data: {
        },
        success:function (data) {
            links = data; -> Here needs to be the first line of the query
            seconds = data2; -> Here needs to be the second line of the query


        }
    });
```

I want to get the information from get_link.php, get_link.php is something like this:

```
["http://stackoverflow.com", "http://mywebsite.com"]
[10, 100]
```

I want to get the information in plain because i want to define a variable with the links the first line and the seconds, the second line.
Thanks

Comment: Is this returning an array of arrays? Try `data[0]` and `data[1]`.

Comment: do you have control to the php server? make it return a json object, so you can access the data by `data.links` and `data.seconds`

Comment: That information being returned is invalid JSON.  Can you make it valid?  Such as an object with array-of-string properties, or an array of arrays of strings?  Or do you need to parse that response as a string instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the response on the newline character:

```
success: function(data) {
    var lines = data.split('\n');
    var links = JSON.parse(lines[0]);
    var seconds = JSON.parse(lines[1]);
    ...
}
```

But it would be better if you returned a single JSON containing a 2-dimensional array.

```
$seconds = array();
$links = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $seconds[] = $row['seconds'];
    $links[] = $row['links'];
}
echo json_encode(array('seconds' => $seconds, 'links' => $links));
```

Or even better, keep the related data together:

```
$results = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $results[] = array('seconds' => $row['seconds'], 'link' => $row['link']);
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

This will produce:

```
[{"seconds": 10, "link": "http://stackoverflow.com"},
 {"seconds": 100, "link": "http://mywebsite.com"}]
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this?:   $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
  $seconds = 0;
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $links = $row["link"];
    $seconds = $row["seconds"];

  }
  return array($seconds,$links);
}
$array = getlink();
$seconds = $array[0];
$links = $array[1];
$variable = array( 'seconds' => "$seconds",
                   'links' => "$links" );

echo json_encode($variable,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES); Getting this response {"seconds":"100","links":"http://stackoverflow.com"}

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how you should do it.

Comment: Ok,and in the javascript how can i do it? Sorry but im new in javascript.Thanks

Comment: After parsing the JSON, it's `data[i].seconds` and `data[i].link`

Answer (score 0):

If the response is 1 array of array you can access it with data[0] and data[1].
If the response just contains 2 (or several) objects, I think you can just define your success function like so:

```
success:function (dataLinks, dataSeconds) {
            links = dataLinks; 
            seconds = dataSeconds;
        }
```